# Blender : can't snap to absolute grid

Tags: snapping

I have a single vertex (point) in 3d space. Its position is random, somewhere in 3d space. Now i just want to snap it to any grid point (grid on ground level or Z=0). I activate  'absolute grid snap' , i move the vertex and press ctrl (turn on snap) but there's no way i can snap it to the grid point. Is it possible to do this in Blender ? should be very simple case.

video link : https://youtu.be/KRci5-L3ajk

Comment: @JachymMichal i've just added video link. Anyway, i can snap to grid point if i'm looking from top view, but when i checked in perspective, the vertex/point is not actually snap to the ground (grid)

Comment: It's snapping, but to the 3-dimensional grid in space. This is the correct behaviour

Comment: yes, i know it's snapping to 3d grid xy, yz, yx. But i just want to snap to the visible grid on floor in perspective view. is it impossible ?  right now i have to do it twice in top and left view to get proper position. This is too many steps for such simple task. Is this the only to do it ?

Comment: It *is also* snapping to the floor grid. Just use the blue arrow (z axis) to get to z=0 and then move it using the other arrows :).

Answer (score 1):

When freemoving an object in 3D view, it doesn't respect traditional *up/down/left/right.*
It's keeping the same distance from your viewport camera, which can be confusing.

It's a consequence of navigating 3D space using a 2D mouse cursor/screen.
For precise movement you need to use the arrows.

[image]

Comment: The only problem is it's too many steps just to simply snap to specific grid i want. I hope Blender develop something like adaptive or dynamic grid like in Modo. see this powerful tools to be implemented in Blender : youtube.com/watch?v=1Ms0v0VsJhY  (look at 3:20)

Comment: Right :). You can suggest such improvements here: https://blender.community/c/rightclickselect/.

Answer (score 0):

You can do what you want in two steps, if that's helpful.

First, ensure the point rests on the plane at 0 height.  You could do this using the Item tab in the N panel (so called because the default keyboard shortcut to view it is N).  This will give you the Transform dropdown header part, as such: [image: N panel transform pane]

If you set the Global Z position of a vertex to 0, it will now be on the 0 height plane.

An alternative way would be go to side view and transform it there manually, perhaps using absolute grid snap to ensure it snaps exactly to 0, but as you've said it's at some random position it might be a long way off so setting it numerically may be faster.

Once it's at that coordinate on the Z, when you are moving it with Grab, you can use shift-Z by default to lock the Z coordinate and allow free transformation on the X and Y plane.  With absolute grid snap turned on, this will then mean that it will indeed snap to each of the visible grid intersections on the 'ground' grid.

While this won't speed up taking a set of random points and snapping them to the floor all that much, the axis lock is very fast for things that are already on the floor, to keep them there.

Comment: Apologies, I completely didn't realize this was two years old and likely inactive.  I'll leave the answer in case it's useful to someone but if you think it isn't feel free to delete it.